# install ubuntu touch to my xperia l

Tags: software-installation

i have a phone and its run android 4.1 (jelly bean) I just bought it on 02/19/2013

i interested to try ubuntu touch in this device

so my question is, if ubuntu touch just can be run in android google nexus are the ubuntu can be run at my android sony experia l?

please answer

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, your device is not officially supported.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

That being said, its always possible that it might work, or partially work on your phone. I wouldn't try it if you rely on this device. But if it's for fun, well, it's your call.